# xml to dataframe error because of duplicate subscripts for columns

Tags: r

I am just trying to create a xml file into a dataframe. My file is big and probably because of that i am getting an error when I try to do it. The error is the followingL: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c(graphics = "", :
duplicate subscripts for columns
the code i used is just this:

```
breast_cancer <- xmlParse("breastcancerkegg.xml")
```

```
xmldaraframe <- xmlToDataFrame("breastcancerkegg.xml")
```

if you need a sample of the xml file see the following genome.jp/pathway/hsa05224+H00031

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pathway SYSTEM "https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/xml/KGML_v0.7.2_.dtd">
<!-- Creation date: Apr 11, 2018 17:05:28 +0900 (GMT+9) -->
<pathway name="path:hsa05224" org="hsa" number="05224"
         title="Breast cancer"
         image="https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/pathway/hsa/hsa05224.png"
         link="https://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?hsa05224">
    <entry id="2" name="path:hsa05224" type="map"
        link="https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa05224">
        <graphics name="TITLE:Breast cancer" fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
             type="roundrectangle" x="123" y="58" width="165" height="25"/>
    </entry>
    <entry id="6" name="hsa:2099 hsa:2100" type="gene"
        link="https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa:2099+hsa:2100">
        <graphics name="ESR1, ER, ESR, ESRA, ESTRR, Era, NR3A1..." fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#BFFFBF"
             type="rectangle" x="710" y="187" width="46" height="17"/>
    </entry>
    <entry id="7" name="hsa:2099 hsa:2100" type="gene"
        link="https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa:2099+hsa:2100">
        <graphics name="ESR1, ER, ESR, ESRA, ESTRR, Era, NR3A1..." fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#BFFFBF"
             type="rectangle" x="1041" y="187" width="46" height="17"/>
    </entry>
    <entry id="9" name="cpd:C00951" type="compound"
        link="https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?C00951">
        <graphics name="C00951" fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
             type="circle" x="237" y="190" width="8" height="8"/>
    </entry>
    <entry id="11" name="hsa:1956" type="gene"
        link="https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa:1956">
        <graphics name="EGFR, ERBB, ERBB1, HER1, NISBD2, PIG61, mENA" fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#BFFFBF"
             type="rectangle" x="325" y="593" width="46" height="17"/>
    </entry>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Do you have a link to the entire file? And if not: how big is "big??

Comment: Thanks fort the comment Caspar. check this link https://www.genome.jp/pathway/hsa05224+H00031

Comment: if you download kgml you will find it

Comment: I found it, please add the link in the question. The problem is that `xmlToDataFrame()` "can be used to extract data from an XML document (or sub-document) that has a simple, shallow structure that does appear reasonably commonly". Your source file is too complex; there's multiple pathway nodes, each with multiple entry nodes, each with multiple graphics nodes. I don't know how to fix it; I think at least you should mention in what format you'd like your data frame to be / which data you want to extract. A good starting point would be `xmlToList()` instead of `xmlToDataFrame`.

Comment: Thank Caspar for your response. I added the link. xmlTolist() works thank you. I see your point about the dataframe, but for example if i want to extract just one entry point, do you know what should i do?

Comment: I've added some pointers as a separate answer, they should help you gather the desired data from the XML file. A correction on my previous comment: there is a single `pathway` node, containing multiple `entry` and `relation` nodes. Each `entry` or `relation` contains a single `graphics` or `subtype` node, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer to the comment by OP: how to access specific nodes in an XML document.

I prefer the `xml2` library over the `XML` library. The [xml2 vignettes](https://rdrr.io/cran/xml2/f/vignettes/releases/xml2-1.1.1.Rmd) are recommended reading / reference material.

###### Understanding the data format

The first step is to open the file in an XML browser or in a plain text editor, to look at the structure of the document. We can see that there is one `pathway` node, containing multiple `entry` and `relation` nodes. Each `entry` node contains a `graphics` node, and each `relation` node contains a `subtype` node.

###### Loading XML file

```
library(xml2)
xml <- read_xml('hsa05224.xml')
```

###### Extracting all `entry` nodes

```
entries <- xml_find_all(xml, "/pathway//entry")
```

Here, the `/` in the path refers to the root of the document and `//` is used to separate nodes from their subnodes.

`entries` will now be a list of 130 items (nodes). Each node can have multiple attributes and multiple children. Attributes have a unique name, children can have identical names.

###### Getting information from single nodes

```
> # print entire node
> entries[[1]]
{xml_node}
<entry id="2" name="path:hsa05224" type="map" link="https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa05224">
[1] <graphics name="TITLE:Breast cancer" fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" type="roundrectangle" x="123" y="58" width="165" height="25"/>
 
> # get node path
> xml_path(entries[[1]])
[1] "/pathway/entry[1]"
 
> # get vector of all attributes
> xml_attrs(entries[[1]])
                                               id                                              name                                              type 
                                              "2"                                   "path:hsa05224"                                             "map" 
                                             link 
"https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa05224" 
 
> # get specific attributes
> xml_attr(entries[[1]], 'name')
[1] "path:hsa05224"

> xml_attr(entries[[1]], 'link')
[1] "https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa05224"
 
> # get node name
> xml_name(entries[[1]])
[1] "entry"
 
> # get all sub-nodes inside node
> kids <- xml_children(entries[[1]])
```

In the last step we extracted all children nodes, on each of which we can perform the same operations again, eg:

```
> xml_path(kids[[1]])
[1] "/pathway/entry[1]/graphics"

> xml_attrs(kids[[1]])
                 name               fgcolor               bgcolor                  type                     x                     y 
"TITLE:Breast cancer"             "#000000"             "#FFFFFF"      "roundrectangle"                 "123"                  "58" 
                width                height 
                "165"                  "25" 

> xml_name(kids[[1]])
[1] "graphics"
```

Manually extracting data from these documents mostly involves a lot of `for()` and/or `lapply()`-calls.